# Nextjs css flickering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, css-modules

I'm building a react app using material ui and nextjs. I'm using `<Autocomplete />` component, provided by material UI and override some its styles with my own like this:

```html
<Autocomplete
  classes={{
    root: `${styles[`search__autocomplete`]} ${
      styles[`search--${variant}__autocomplete`]
    }`,
    inputRoot: `${styles[`search__autocomplete-input`]} ${
      styles[`search--${variant}__autocomplete-input`]
    }`
  }} 
/>
```

`variant` is a prop, which gets passed to the component and `styles` is a variable, which get imported from the *css module*: `import styles from "Search.module.sass"`.

Now, when I'm working on this locally everything looks great:

[image: expected]

But, after I deploy it to production via `next build && next export` I start experiencing "flickering" effect when for like 1/3 of a second my page looks like this:

[image]

My guess is that it might be related to the fact that nextjs export my css to several files on production:

```html
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_next/static/css/4dcd7fa805fb41261f08.css"
      as="style"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/_next/static/css/4dcd7fa805fb41261f08.css"
      data-n-g=""
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_next/static/css/a23cf79bceae4047fddb.css"
      as="style"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/_next/static/css/a23cf79bceae4047fddb.css"
      data-n-p=""
    />
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to create a custom `pages/_document.js` page with:

```js
import React from 'react';
// Modules
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
// MUI Core
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with server-side rendering (SSR).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
    enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
  });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
  };
};

export default MyDocument;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by the `<CacheProvider>` component of `@emotion/react` removing it from `_app.js` file fixed the problem for me

Nextjs is now supporting SSR with emotion you can enable it this way in `next.config.js` file :

```js
const nextConfig = {
  //...
  compiler: {
    emotion: true,
  },
};
```

Also if using `<CssBaseline/>` component of Material UI replace it with `<ScopedCssBaseline>`

> However, you might be progressively migrating a website to MUI, using a global reset might not be an option. It's possible to apply the baseline only to the children by using the ScopedCssBaseline component.

```
import { ScopedCssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
//...
<ScopedCssBaseline>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</ScopedCssBaseline>
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

interface IFadeInProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

function FadeIn(props: IFadeInProps) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShow(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ opacity: show ? 1 : 0 }}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FadeIn;
```

I use tailwindcss in next.js. Use this to fix it.